# My strcpy isn't working even if I allocate memory to my pointer struct

Tags: c

I tried to allocate memory to my struct but it didn't work. Here is the piece of my programme where it goes wrong (also the declaration of the structs).

```
struct ptr {
    int tel;
    char nome;
    struct ptr *prox;
};

struct reg{
    char letra;
    struct ptr *inicio;
};

struct reg agenda[26];

agenda[l].inicio = (struct ptr*)malloc(sizeof(struct ptr));
agenda[l].inicio->prox = (struct ptr*)NULL;
strcpy(agenda[l].inicio->nome,nome);
```

Comment: the `nome` is just a `char` not an array of `char`.

Comment: Don't you get diagnostics from your compiler?! Makes a pointer from integer yada yada...

Comment: Did you mean to write `char *nome` and allocate for `agenda[l].inicio->nome` as well, or did you mean `agenda[l].inicio->nome = nome;`?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the nome char to a char pointer. Also before strcpy you have to allocate memory for the pointer.

```
struct ptr {
    int tel;
    char *nome;
    struct ptr *prox;
};

struct reg{
    char letra;
    struct ptr *inicio;
};

struct reg agenda[26];

agenda[l].inicio = (struct ptr*)malloc(sizeof(struct ptr));
agenda[l].inicio->prox = (struct ptr*)NULL;
agenda[l].inicio->nome = (char*)malloc(MAX_NOME_LENGTH);
strcpy(agenda[l].inicio->nome,nome);
```

Of course change `MAX_NOME_LENGTH` to the maximum size of the string.

Comment: If you're going to allocate a fixed length for the name (`nome`), you may as well just make it a character array: `char nome[MAX_NOME_LENGTH];` and avoid the separate allocation.   Better would be to use `strdup()` to allocate and copy the string: `agenda[l].inicio->nome = strdup(nome);`